# Setting up a fully runnable project with Qt for Python and Cmake in Qt Creator

Tags: python, c++, qt, cmake, pyside2

I have recently started to look at Qt for Python and I installed `PySide2` on my system via `pip install PySide2`. Now I read some beginner tutorials on the Qt documentation site and was able to run simple program such [this](https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_for_Python_Tutorial_HelloQML).
However, I don't understand how I can I set up a fully runnable PySide2 project in Qt Creator. I know that PySide2 requires CMake, but I am unsure on how can I set up a project. I have this [blog post](https://blog.qt.io/blog/2018/05/31/write-python-bindings/) which shows how to write custom C++ bindings for PySide2 and link a [sample project](https://code.qt.io/cgit/pyside/pyside-setup.git/tree/examples/samplebinding?h=5.9). In the sample project I can see there is `CMakeLists.txt` file. I cloned the sample and open `CMakeLists.txt` file in Qt Creator, which tells me that I need to set up a configuration kit to open the project. However, I am a bit clueless on how to do so.